# How to set up a staging table in SQL with SSIS dataflow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create a dataflow in SSIS where the source data originates from an excel file and reaches to a temporary staging table in a SQL server where I can add various stored procedures to the data.

The dataflow that I have created stores the data permanently on what is supposed to be the staging area.

I would like to get some ideas on creating the staging table in SQL with the SSIS dataflow.

Comment: *"I would like to get some ideas on creating the staging table in SQL with the SSIS dataflow."* What "ideas" do you need; you just need to `CREATE` the table...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit confusing. I suppose that you are maybe trying to make the data loaded in the table of the staging area temporary without keeping the past loaded data.

If I'm right what you're trying to accomplish is a "full resfresh" data flow.

From your description I assume you alerady have the staging table (so no nedd to `CREATE` it) but you need to truncate it at every run. You can achive this by using a *Execut SQL Task* element to the *control flow* with a `TRUNCATE TABLE <YOUR TABLE NAME>` in it. The data flow loading the data must be in dependency of this task with the result of truncating your table at every run.

If you need to `CREATE` a table you can do it in the control flow with the [Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-ver16) (you can execute any kind of query with this task), rember to set correctly the connection manager of the task.